# Binding AutoHotkey tray menu entries to functions?

Tags: function, contextmenu, autohotkey, system-tray, subroutine

The AutoHotkey command [`Menu`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Menu.htm) lets you customize the context-menu of the script’s notification area icon, but it seems to require labels/subroutines to be attached to menu entries.

I have some functions that while I *could* convert to subroutines, I would prefer not to since they are easier and clearer to use and also have locals which would require refactoring to be converted. Moreover, functions are not automatically executed and must be called, while subroutines are simply labeled sections of code, so they require extra work to avoid being called unwittingly. In fact, the AHK man page for `Gosub` specifically suggests to use functions instead:

> Although Gosub is useful for simple, general purpose subroutines, consider using functions for more complex purposes.

One obvious drawback to subroutines is that they cannot take arguments.

Is there a way to create menu entries that are bound to functons?

Comment: @hit-and-run–down-voter, what’s your problem? No, really; without an explanatory comment, I can’t address any issues you may have (if any *sigh*) with the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can have each subroutine call a corresponding function.

Comment: If I am creating subroutines anyway, then why would I bother with functions? I still have to re-factor to prevent the subroutines from being executed (I learned that the hard way since I used to have my functions at the top an was wondering why the script was freezing when I changed them the subroutines).

Comment: How would the subroutines be executed?

Comment: Because subroutines are nothing more than a label. If the block of code happens to be in the middle of execution (like it was when I converted the functions at the top of my script to subroutines by replacing the `()` after the function names to `:`), then the lines below the labels will be executed.

Comment: Well, yes; but only standalone lines. AHK won't execute subroutines until they are `GoSub`'d or invoked with a hotkey.

Comment: It won’t *branch* to subroutines in other parts of the script, but if they are in the way, it will bulldoze right on through them.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that about subroutines defined in the auto-execute section. It looks like all you need to do to prevent it is to put a `Return` before the start of subroutine definitions.

Comment: [I know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658528/binding-autohotkey-tray-menu-entries-to-functions/12664221#comment17232329_12752744).

Answer (score 1):

Subroutines don't automatically execute if you use your `return` statements properly.

As a rule, have a `return` at the end of each subroutine or multi-line hotkey (Single-line hotkeys don't need that). (A function's execution terminates at the closing brace, so you don't need a return, unless of course you want to return a value, or end termination at some other point in the function.)

Also, ensure you define any subroutine outside the **auto-execute** section of the script, to prevent it from automatically executing when the script starts.

More about the "auto-execute" section from AHK docs:

> The Top of the Script (the Auto-execute Section) After the script has
>   been loaded, it begins executing at the top line, continuing until a
>   Return, Exit, hotkey/hotstring label, or the physical end of the
>   script is encountered (whichever comes first). This top portion of the
>   script is referred to as the auto-execute section.
>
> A script that is not persistent and that lacks hotkeys, hotstrings,
>   OnMessage, and GUI will terminate after the auto-execute section has
>   completed. Otherwise, it will stay running in an idle state,
>   responding to events such as hotkeys, hotstrings, GUI events, custom
>   menu items, and timers.

**EDIT**:
Unfortunately, you still cannot bind direction function calls to menus, because that's not supported.
But you could call your functions from within the corresponding subroutines (now that you know how to keep them from running automatically). By exposing some state globally you can eliminate the need to pass arguments to your functions. However, if you don't want to do that, you can simply create variables initialized to whatever values you want to pass to the "bound" function at that point, and then using them to make the equivalent of the the "bound" function call that you wanted to make. For example:

```
subroutine:
arg1 = <some expression>
arg2 = <some expression>
MyFunction(arg1, arg1)
return

MyFunction(a, b) 
....
}
```

Comment: *> Subroutines don't automatically execute if you use your return statements properly.*   Yes, I know, and I did that (but still moved the subroutines to the end anyway). However that doesn’t answer this question.

Comment: Why pass the args if they are global (and why make them global if you can pass them)?

Comment: @echristopherson, they’re not global, they are strings (at least in my case).

Comment: @echristopherson
A couple of reasons why one would want to do this
1) This way the values the function **actually** depends on are **not** global and cannot be accidentally modified by external code.
2) Now you can do suff like call the function recursively (which generally requires the function to have **local** arguments passed to it)
[I have edited my post a bit to make it clearer, in particular changing the names of the variables g_arg1, g_arg2 to simply arg1, arg2 because the former seemed to imply that some internal state had been globally exposed, which wasn't the case]